# Were $ and $$ introduced as aliases for querySelector/All?

Tags: javascript, dom

When I do `$('body')` in the browser console on an empty page it returns the body node as `querySelector` does. I tried that in FF and Chrome and it just works.

Can you tell me if this is a public api? When was it introduced and where it is defined? Also a link to the mdn docs would help (which I coudlnt find)